# How does one multi factor auth an API?

Tags: android, ios, security, oauth-2.0

So username/password isn't secure enough in a lot of cases. Usually on a website, a user logs in and uses 2FA from Google Authenticator or Authy, but we need this to persist if a user logs in **via API** (In particular a mobile app consuming an API). It needs to persist because the mobile app or API may be continuously hitting authorized endpoints and we can't expect a new 2FA every time you try and do something.

As a general rule I've never seen a mobile app utilize 2FA with a code like this. I was thinking that you can grab something (ID?) about the device, and have it authorized along with the username/password oauth token. This way ONLY that device may make requests using that combination of credentials. I feel like this could be spoofed, so how do you make this secure?

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but what is a good way to enforce a high level of security using multi-factor auth for an API and/or mobile device?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about your exact use case, but if this is a mobile only situation and you really need to make sure only that a particular device logs in you may consider payfone's sim card based authentication. With payfone they don't even need to log in, payfone would just be able to check out their sim card and authenticate them.

Comment: This is normally handled using OAuth. The app needs a token to access the api. It triggers an oauth flow where some authentication provider verifies the user in whatever way it needs to (username/password, 2FA etc). It then returns the token to the app which is included with the api requests. On the back end the api verifies the token. The token has a lifetime but a refresh endpoint can typically be called before that lifetime expires to get a new token without user interaction. There are various open source oauth frameworks available and you can also get services from companies like Auth0

Comment: @Paulw11 It is OAuth already but OAuth is not secure enough. It's only as secure as the username/password combination. What I need is multi-factor but in the sense of an API. You can't multi-factor every request without causing the user a large amount of grief (every call will need a new code). Locking the device in seems to be the right idea, but I'm not sure if there's a particular way to do it.

Comment: But, I guess I can modify our OAuth flow to include a device ID of sorts which would have to match before issuing the token. That's kind of where I was going with this I guess.

Comment: Oauth isn't limited to username/password. it isn't generally your api's responsibility to worry about 2FA. It simply consumes the token. The identity provider should enforce 2FA when minting the token, if required.  You can have policy that requires 2FA always, or only when not on a certain network or even  only if a 2FA hasn't been provided within a certain recent period. Access policy isn't your api's concern.

Comment: Ah, I am the identity provider, I've exposed one of my own APIs for another project to use. I will need to build the 2FA in to my own API so the other system can consume it, but it is absolutely critical that this multi-factor is in place. Basically I have control over both parts of this, It's just that I can log in to the API using `password_grant` OAuth type, and it only takes username/password. It needs something else so that someone with malicious intent cannot just hit the API using a users username/password combination.